# How to filter log messages above a certain response size in App Engine Log viewer?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-logging

Based on the LogViewer [documenation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced_filters) I am hoping to be able to use httpRequest FIELDS in an expression to filter log messages.

Within the Advanced Filter, I have tried to use

```
httpRequest.responseSize > 10000
```

But has not worked. Any suggestion on what I might be doing wrong or if there is any other way to do this.

I am using logger from the console (https://console.developers.google.com/logs). Please note that I have appended the above line to the others that 'convert to advance filter' shows as follows.

```
metadata.serviceName="appengine.googleapis.com"
metadata.labels."appengine.googleapis.com/module_id"="default"
metadata.labels."appengine.googleapis.com/version_id"="myAppId"
log="appengine.googleapis.com/request_log"
metadata.severity>=INFO
httpRequest.responseSize > 10000
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following

protoPayload.responseSize>10000

Comment: Btw, where is this in the documentation. I see that responseSize is part of the httpRequest, but could not find where it mentions protoPayload. I am keen on seeing what other FIELDS are available in protoPayload (for example, can I do protoPayload.requestSize ?)

Comment: You can expand requests from [log viewer](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/project/_/logs) interface to explore other captured fields inside protoPayload object. I recommend submitting a feature request [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/) for the doc update.